# Need some help on how to implement an restfull api app based on golang

Tags: python, api, go

My coding skills are a bit low :)
Recently i started learning golang and how to handle an Api communication app. Have been having a great time learning it by myself, golang is revealing itself as a challenging language with great rewards in the end (code sense ^^).

Have been trying to create a cryptsy api lib for golang based on their API V2 (BETA) which is a restfull api. They have a python lib on their api website https://github.com/ScriptProdigy/CryptsyPythonV2/blob/master/Cryptsy.py.

So far have been able to get the public access working but am having a really hard time at the private access because of the authentication part.. I find that the info they give on their website on how to implement it is a bit confusing :(

> Authorization is performed by sending the following variables into the request header Key
>
> - Public API key.
> - All query data (nonce=blahblah&limit=blahblah) signed by a secret key according to HMAC-SHA512 method. Your secret key and public keys can be generated from your account settings page. Every request requires a unique nonce. (Suggested to use unix timestamp with microseconds)

For this authentication part the python code goes as:

```
def _query(self, method, id=None, action=None, query=[], get_method="GET"):
    query.append(('nonce', time.time()))
    queryStr = urllib.urlencode(query)

    link = 'https://' + self.domain + route

    sign = hmac.new(self.PrivateKey.encode('utf-8'), queryStr, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

    headers = {'Sign': sign, 'Key': self.PublicKey.encode('utf-8')}
```

Got this far in golang:

```
package main

import(

    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha512"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"

)

const (

    API_BASE_CRY    = "https://api.cryptsy.com/api/"
    API_VERSION_CRY = "v2"
    API_KEY_CRY     = "xxxxx"
    API_SECRET_CRY  = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    DEFAULT_HTTPCLIENT_TIMEOUT = 30 // HTTP client timeout
)

type clientCry struct {
    apiKey     string
    apiSecret  string
    httpClient *http.Client
}

type Cryptsy struct {
    clientCry *clientCry
}

type CryptsyApiRsp struct {
    Success bool            `json:"success"`
    Data    json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

func NewCry(apiKey, apiSecret string) *Cryptsy {
    clientCry := NewClientCry(apiKey, apiSecret)
    return &Cryptsy{clientCry}
}

func NewClientCry(apiKey, apiSecret string) (c *clientCry) {
    return &clientCry{apiKey, apiSecret, &http.Client{}}
}

func ComputeHmac512Hex(secret, payload string) string {
    h := hmac.New(sha512.New, []byte(secret))
    h.Write([]byte(payload))
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func (c *clientCry) doTimeoutRequestCry(timer *time.Timer, req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {

    type data struct {
       resp *http.Response
       err  error
    }

    done := make(chan data, 1)
    go func() {
       resp, err := c.httpClient.Do(req)
       done <- data{resp, err}
    }()

    select {
       case r := <-done:
       return r.resp, r.err
       case <-timer.C:
          return nil, errors.New("timeout on reading data from Bittrex API")
    }
}

func (c *clientCry) doCry(method string, ressource string, payload string, authNeeded bool) (response []byte, err error) {
    connectTimer := time.NewTimer(DEFAULT_HTTPCLIENT_TIMEOUT * time.Second)

    var rawurl string        

    nonce := time.Now().UnixNano()
    result :=  fmt.Sprintf("nonce=%d", nonce)
    rawurl = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s/%s?%s", API_BASE_CRY ,API_VERSION_CRY , ressource, result )
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, rawurl, strings.NewReader(payload))

    sig := ComputeHmac512Hex(API_SECRET_CRY, result)

    req.Header.Add("Sign", sig)
    req.Header.Add("Key", API_KEY_CRY )

    resp, err := c.doTimeoutRequestCry(connectTimer, req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    response, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("reponse %s", response), err)
    return response, err
}

func main() {

    crypsy := NewCry(API_KEY_CRY, API_SECRET_CRY)
    r, _ := crypsy.clientCry.doCry("GET", "info", "", true) 
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

and my output is :

`response {"success":false,"error":["Must be authenticated"]} <nil>`

not getting why :( im passing the public key and the signature in the header, the signature.. i think im doing it right in the hmac-sha512.
I'm quering the user info url https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/apiv2/user, which as stated in the api site  doesn't have any extra query variables so the nonce is the only one needed..

Have googled about restfull api's but haven't been able to find any answer :( starting to not let me sleep at night since i think that what im doing is kinda right.. really cant spot the error..

Anyone out there that could try and help me with this?

Thxs a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the issue with `result :=  fmt.Sprintf("%d", nonce)`. The code that corresponds to the Python code should be something like

```
result :=  fmt.Sprintf("nonce=%d", nonce)
```

Could you please check it with this fix?

I also can observe a major difference in how the request is sending. The Python version is ([link](https://github.com/ScriptProdigy/CryptsyPythonV2/blob/master/Cryptsy.py)):

```
        ret = requests.get(link,
                           params=query,
                           headers=headers,
                           verify=False)
```

but your code is does not send `params` with added nonce, etc. I think it should be something like

```
rawurl = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s/%s?%s", API_BASE_CRY ,API_VERSION_CRY , ressource, queryStr)
```

where queryStr should contain nonce, etc.

Comment: Im really sorry! first time posting on stackoverflow. edited the code and now is copy paste able and executes. I think i might be missing some kind of encode for the response when i pass it to the ComputeHmac512Hex method.

Comment: I'll try in a sec! Yeah i only made it without params because i think the info url doesnt need anymore parameters, but the nonce. Still not sure on that, but yes the correct implementation would be with the full parameters. But i think the query data (parameters) is to be added to the header not to the rawurl, at least thats what i get from their description on the variables to send to them. **Update** just tryed and still doesnt work, i might be missing an encode on the result :x python code: queryStr = urllib.urlencode(query)

Comment: Most likely you need to send the parameters as well: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: They are definitely added to the query string so please try with full URL.

Comment: added this code: nonce := time.Now().UnixNano()
        result :=  fmt.Sprintf("nonce=%d", nonce)
        rawurl = fmt.Sprintf("%s%s/%s?%s", API_BASE_CRY ,API_VERSION_CRY , ressource, result ) ... like this? still cant do it

Comment: I updated the question :) but still cant seem to make this run properly

Comment: I've just tested the code with Cryptsy and it works well. `reponse {"success":true,"data":{"id":"336571","username":"AlexAtNet","accounttype":"Personal","email":...`. Make sure that your key/secret in the right order. The secret is longer. I mean that it literally works as it is now.

Comment: Make sure that you have got your keys from Cryptsy account page, API Keys section.

Comment: reponse {"success":true,"data":{"id":"332744","username":"MikePal",.....   :D Thank you Alex :D